# ASP.NET mvc - long lasting result from response is not performed in ajax callback

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-ajax

Good day,
I have web application written in asp. When long lasting result is executed in controller so response is not sending to ajax:

```
.done(function (result) {
    if (result.success) {
        //successful result - from controller 
    } else {
         //successful result - from controller
  }});
```

Application is hosted in IIS on three different servers. Two servers always return long lasting result from controller to ajax's client .done without problem but one of them never returns long lasting result to ajax's client.  I guess that it's some setting in IIS, which is concerning response's duration but I do not know what I should set exactly.

Give me please some advice.
Thank you

Comment: "response is not sending"...so what response is coming back instead? Some error? Anything else? Or it just times out? The nature of the error might give you a clue about the best way to resolve it. Check your browser's console and / or network tools to see what's actually going on with the request.

Comment: There should be some response sent by server
You can use error callback to get error
You can also user **Chrome Developer tools -> Network** to check what response was sent

Comment: I guess that is timeout as concerning response (but I dont know how to set in iis how long client can wait for result), but request is normally comming to server. In controller action is executing all things. I check the log on server; in last the last phase is "controller' s action return":
return Json(new { success = !model.IsErrorMessage, id = model.IdModel, message = model.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 

and It always get to ajax .done even if model has some error. But when action is lasting long on the specific server, the redirection is not firing to ajax .done.

Comment: "I guess that is timeout"...instead of guessing go and look in your browser network tools as has been mentioned twice already. Error logs / event viewer on the IIS server might also give some clues.